# Problem in viewing MathJax formatted writing in smartphone

Tags: support, bug, mathjax

I access this site using Chrome from myou smartphone. Recently, the MathJax formatted writings appear overlapped, for example in the following answer:

[image]

What could be the reason for this?

Update: problem continues on math SE also. See below.

[image]

Another:

[image]

I've cleared chrome  (v58) data, cache, browsing history, cookies, everything.

Phone is Samsung Galaxy On7 with Android 6.0-marshmallow.

Comment: As usual with this type of bug, you should supply the exact versions of the browser and OS you're using.

Comment: You should also update add-on, clear caches, and make other local attempts to insure that it is really a problem. Though I am less certain of which of those you can do on mobile browsers (or how to do them).

Comment: @dmckee Done all. Cleared browsing data, cache, and the rest, but problem persists.

Comment: @Emilio Chrome is of version 58.0.3029.83 (latest)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce is on Chrome 58. What OS are you using? Also, make sure to restart chrome after clearing the cache.

Comment: @Peter Android 6.0-marshmallow on Samsung Galaxy On7. Already tried your methods.

Comment: @WrichikBasu I'm afraid I can't reproduce this on 6.0.1, Chrome 58. A workaround might be switching the output to SVG via the mathjax menu (double-tap&hold, can be a little tricky to trigger).

Comment: Does the problem persist in other SE sites? What about other sites in the [MathJax Gallery of Selected Sites](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/misc/mathjax-in-use.html#gallery-of-selected-sites)? It's pretty obvious that this bug doesn't have a wide reach, so I would advise you to try things from a wider register that will help diagnose this. Ultimately, you could also [raise an issue on the MathJax page](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues) if you don't find a fix.

Comment: Yes, it does. @Emilio

Comment: Yes to which question? If the behaviour also appears on other sites beyond SE, it's out of our hands - you should raise an issue on the GitHub home.

Comment: Not beyond SE sites, but also in other SE sites, not only Physics SE.